# .click, Find next class element in parent, fade in, remove class. Repeat

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-selectors, html-lists

Ideally, im trying to click a div, find the next class within a parent. fade in that class, remove the class.

Click div again, then find next class of 'page', fades in, remove the class.

Any help would be great. Currently, .find, .next, .nextAll is resulting in all ul with the class page to fade in at once.

HTML

```
<div id="container" class="">
    <ul id="page_1">
    <ul id="page_2" class="page">
    <ul id="page_3" class="page">
    <ul id="page_4" class="page">
    </div>
```

JS

```
$("#click").click(function() { 
    $("#container").children().closest('.page').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    var active;
    if ($('#container > .active').length) {
        active = $('#container > .active');
        active.removeClass('active');
        active.next().addClass('active');
        active = active.next();
    } else {
        active = $('#container > .page:first');
        active.addClass('active');
    }
    active.fadeIn();
});
```

(Your markup i s not correct this assumes:)

```
<div id="container" class="">
    <ul id="page_1"></ul>
    <ul id="page_2" class="page"></ul>
    <ul id="page_3" class="page"></ul>
    <ul id="page_4" class="page"></ul>
 </div>
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kmtCV/2/

Comment: Works for me; I interpreted the original question as wanting to remove "page" though: http://jsfiddle.net/kmtCV/1/ Also: just noticed that the second click doesn't work; something's out of order and I didn't trouble-shoot.

Comment: @GregPettit sorry corected that in my post

Comment: Yup, that works. I still think the post asks for "page" to be removed, and also after the last click happens. If so (may not be!) that's just a matter of revising the timing: http://jsfiddle.net/kmtCV/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#click').click(function() { 
    $('#container > .page:first').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: I think that he wants to fade them in one a time, but maybe i'm wrong!

Comment: Yes, it looks like one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As a `.page` element is fading in, you can add a `visible` class to it, which you exclude using `:not` as a selector when fading the next element. See http://jsfiddle.net/rTfcy/